# Erro comunicação PHP e C#

Tags: php, c#

Estou tentando mandar um dado de C# para o PHP, mas o exemplo que encontro e todas as soluções simplesmente resultam no mesmo erro.

```
 using System.Net;
 using System.Collections.Specialized;

        string valor = "1";

        string urlAddress = "http://localhost:80/Untitled-1.php";

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {

            NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection()
   {
          { "valor", valor}

   };


            client.UploadValues(urlAddress, postData);

        }
```

Código em PHP pra receber os dados:

```
<html>

<?php
      $valor = $_POST["valor"];  

echo $valor;
 ?>
```

Erro no PHP:

> Notice: Undefined index: valor in C:\xampp\htdocs\Untitled-1.php on line 4

É um código bem simples, mas é a base de um programa maior. Alguém tem idéia do que pode ser?

Comment: Boa noite, Pode ser que seu php não está dando permissão para leitura externa... Tenta atribuir isso no topo do seu arquivo: <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?> Dúvidas, estou à disposição.

Comment: Tente dar um var_dump($_POST), se não informar nenhum valor, possa ser que sua aplicação c# esta com algum problema.

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho certeza, mas creio que seja por falta definir o `Content-Type` da requisição, assim:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

string valor = "1";

string urlAddress = "http://localhost:80/Untitled-1.php";

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection()
    {
         { "valor", valor }
    };

    client.UploadValues(urlAddress, postData);
}
```

---

Esse problema não tem nada haver com `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, o `WebClient` não é um site tentando acessar outro, é um cliente tentando acessar um site, então não tem **origens cruzadas**. Aplicar o `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` no PHP não resolve nada e mesmo que fosse um problema relacionado ao CORS você nem conseguiria obter o erro gerado no PHP.